# Fortran's performance

Tags: performance, comparison, fortran, benchmarking

Fortran's performances on [Computer Language Benchmark Game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/) are surprisingly bad. Today's result puts Fortran 14th and 11th on the two quad-core tests, 7th and 10th on the single cores.

Now, I know benchmarks are never perfect, but still, Fortran was (is?) often considered THE language for high performance computing and it seems like the type of problems used in this benchmark should be to Fortran's advantage. In an recent article on computational physics, [Landau (2008) wrote:](http://physics.orst.edu/~rubin/Papers/CP-2.pdf)

> However, [Java] is not as efficient or
>   as well supported for HPC and parallel
>   processing as are FORTRAN and C, the
>   latter two having highly developed
>   compilers and many more scientific
>   subroutine libraries available.
>   FORTRAN, in turn, is still the
>   dominant language for HPC, with
>   FORTRAN 90/95 being a surprisingly
>   nice, modern, and effective language;
>   but alas, it is hardly taught by any
>   CS departments, and compilers can be
>   expensive.

Is it only because of the compiler used by the language shootout (Intel's free compiler for Linux) ?

Comment: reverse-complement seems to stand out as a particularly bad result for Fortran.

Comment: And what kind of processing would you say "reverse-complement" does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this isn't just because of the compiler.

What benchmarks like this -- where the program differs from benchmark to benchmark -- is largely the amount of effort (and quality of effort) that the programmer put into writing any given program.  I suspect that Fortran is at a significant disadvantage in that particular metric -- unlike C and C++, the pool of programmers who'd want to try their hand at making the benchmark program better is pretty small, and unlike most anything else, they likely don't feel like they have something to prove either.  So, there's no motivation for someone to spend a few days poring over generated assembly code and profiling the program to make it go faster.

This is fairly clear from the results that were obtained.  In general, with sufficient programming effort and a decent compiler, neither C, C++, nor Fortran will be significantly slower than assembly code -- certainly not more than 5-10%, at worst, except for pathological cases.  The fact that the actual results obtained here are more variant than that indicates to me that "sufficient programming effort" has not been expended.

There are exceptions when you allow the assembly to use vector instructions, but don't allow the C/C++/Fortran to use corresponding compiler intrinsics -- automatic vectorization is not even a close approximation of perfect and probably never will be.  I don't know how much those are likely to apply here.

Similarly, an exception is in things like string handling, where you depend heavily on the runtime library (which may be of varying quality; Fortran is rarely a case where a fast string library will make money for the compiler vendor!), and on the basic definition of a "string" and how that's represented in memory.

Answer (score 3):

This benchmark is stupid at all.

For example, they measure CPU-time for [the whole program to run](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/help.php#measure). As mcmint [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196814/fortrans-performance/3755940#3755940) (and it might be actually true) Fortran I/O sucks*.  But who cares? In real-world tasks one read input for some seconds than do calculations for hours/days/months and finally write output for the seconds. Thats why in most benchmarks I/O operations are excluded from time measurements (if you of course do not benchmark I/O by itself).

Norber Wiener in his book God & Golem, Inc. wrote

> Render unto man the things which are man’s and unto the computer the things which are the computer’s.

In my opinion the usage of this principle while implementing algorithm in any programming language means:

> Write as readable and simple code as you can and let compiler do the optimizations.

Especially it is important in real-world (huge) applications. Dirty tricks (so heavily used in many benchmarks) even if they might improve the efficiency to some extent (5%, maybe 10%) are not for the real-world projects.

/* C/C++ uses stream I/O, but Fortran traditionally uses record-based I/O. [Further reading](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Stream+Input+Output). Anyway I/O in that benchmarks are so surprising. The usage of stdin/stdout redirection might also be the source of problem. Why not simply use the ability of reading/writing files provided by the language or standard library? Once again this woud be more real-world situation.

Answer (score 2):

Some random thoughts:

Fortran used to do very well because it was easier to identify loop invariants which made some optimizations easier for the compiler. Since then

1. Compilers have gotten *much* more sophisticated. Enormous effort has been put into c and c++ compilers in particular. Have the fortran compilers kept up? I suppose the gfortran uses the same back end of gcc and g++, but what of the intel compiler? It used to be good, but is it still?
2. Some languages have gotten a lot specialized keywords and syntax to help the compiler (`restricted` and `const int const *p` in c, and `inline` in c++). Not knowing fortran 90 or 95 I can't say if these have kept pace.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at these tests. It's not like the compiler is wrong or something. In most tests Fortran is comparable to C++ except some where it gets beaten by a factor of 10. These tests just reflect what one should know from the beggining - that Fortran is simply NOT an all-around interoperable programming language - it is suited for efficient computation, has good list operations & stuff but for example IO sucks unless you are doing it with specific Fortran-like methods - like e.g. 'unformatted' IO.

Let me give you an example - the 'reverse-complement' program that is supposed to read a large (of order of 10^8 B) file from stdin line-by-line, does something with it & prints the resulting large file to stdout. The pretty straighforward Fortran program is about 10 times slower on a single core (~10s) than a HEAVILY optimized C++ (~1s). When you try to play with the program, you'll see that only simple formatted read & write take more than 8 seconds. In a Fortran way, if you care for efficiency, you'd just write an unformatted structure to a file & read it back in no time (which is totally non-portable & stuff but who cares anyway - an efficient code is supposed to be fast & optimized for a specific machine, not able to run everywhere).

So the short answer is - don't worry, just do your job - and if you want to write a super-efficient operating system, than sorry - Fortran is just not the way for that kind of performance.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to say that even if the benchmark do not bring up the best results for FORTRAN, this language will still be used and for a long time. Reasons of use are not just performance but also some kind of thing called easyness of programmability. Lots of people that learnt to use it in the 60's and 70's are now too old for getting into new stuff and they know how to use FORTRAN pretty well. I mean, there are a lot of human factors for a language to be used. The programmer also matters.

Answer (score 1):

Considering they did not publish the exact compiler options they used for the Intel Fortran Compiler, I have little faith in their benchmark.

I would also remark that both Intel's math library, MKL, and AMD's math library, ACML, use the Intel Fortran Compiler.

Edit:

I did find the compilation options when you click on the benchmark's name.  The result is surprising since the optimization level seems reasonable.  It may come down to the efficiency of the algorithm.

Comment: "I did find the compilation options" And still the first line of your comment says they are not published!

Comment: Readers stop reading quickly, plenty will stop reading after your first misleading sentence - fix that first sentence!